# why does initializing gradle doesnt work?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

im trying to run my first flutter app and stucked at this error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A510F in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Finished with error: ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\flutter_app1\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: C:\Users\DELL\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv\gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
  Command: C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\flutter_app1\android\gradlew.bat -v
```

Comment: permission issue?

Comment: try with invalidate caches/restart.

Comment: now I opened .gradle folder and see that there is a file named gradle-4.1-all.zip.part .. is that a problem?

Comment: Try to remove the `.gradle` folder. It seems you go a time-out while downloading gradle. How fast is your internet connection?

Comment: very very slow, 40kb/s

Comment: can I download it manually??

Comment: You can try to execute `C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\flutter_app1\android\gradlew.bat -version`. This should download gradle and show it's version. Once you have it downloaded it is cached and not downloaded again.

Answer (score 0):

Try flutter clean and then migrating to androidX.

Right mouse click on your app folder in AS then refractor - > migrate to androidX

Most gradle issues are solved by migrating to androidX